# unable to get value of get parameter in url with #

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am unable to get the value of a `GET` parameter in my URL.

My url is like

```
abc.com/new.php#tabs-11?val=100
```

I want to get value of `val`

```
<?php echo $_GET['val'];
```

This is not working, please tell what to do.

Comment: You can't get fragments. The reason being, the browser doesn't actually send that part of the URL to your server. You can retrieve it with JavaScript however. You'll want to rearrange your URL so that val comes first.

Comment: what can i do get that value via juqey

Comment: @user1799722, see my answer below for how to get that value using jquery... However, it is very important to note that your url is wrong, and if you have control over it, the # should go after the ?. (Anything after # is considered named anchor, even a ?, so there are technically no GET variables in your url).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That URL makes no sense. You need to have the query string before the fragment:

```
abc.com/new.php?val=100#tabs-11
```

Stuff after `#` is not parsed as part of the URL by the server. It may not even be sent by the browser.

Comment: @user1799722 You have two options: change your code, or alter the entire way the HTTP protocol works and reprogram every browser ever written.

Answer (score 1):

`#tabs-11?val=100` would be considered an Anchor for the in this instance.  Make sure that you put your Anchors at the end of the query string

Answer (score 0):

When a url has a "#" in it, that points to a "named anchor", or a "fragment". It isn't part of the "GET" variables... So, you can't get it that way. In fact, the server doesn't even know anything about it.

Since you tagged this with jquery as well, javascript can actually do that.

```
var url = window.location.href;
```

This will give you the full url. From there, you can just search for substrings.

```
var anchor = url.substring(url.indexOf("#"));
var gets = anchor.substring(anchor.indexOf("?"));
```

Although, I would like to point out that your url is incorrect. The anchor should go *after* the get variables.

Comment: You don't need to do that. You can simply do `window.location.hash` and `window.location.search`. See [`window.location` on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location).

Comment: @lonesomeday, you are completely right. I'm not sure if that will work on the OP's malformed url though... :)

Comment: No, it won't. `search` will be empty and `hash` will contain the query string.