# express.js request.query is empty

Tags: javascript, express, google-oauth

I have redirect URL from google OAuth2,
`http://localhost:997/?#state=pass-through%20value&access_token=ya29.ImC6B1g9LYsf5siso8n_UphOFB0SXc5dqsm6LqHRWXbtNHisEblxjeLoYtGgwSVtCTGxOjjODiuTyH7VCHoZCEfUd_&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`

problem shows up when I want to get access_token from it.

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  port = process.env.PORT || 997;

app.get("/", (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.query);
    res.send("hi");
});

app.get("/url", (req, res, next) => {
    res.json('test');
});

app.listen(port, ()=>{
  console.log("Server on port: " + port);
});
```

output after going on site:

```
`[nodemon] starting `node main.js`
Server on port: 997
{}
```

After removing `#state=pass-through%20value`, so link looks `http://localhost:997/?&access_token=ya29.Il-6B4zOwiM7bLeWcyJX9iQGuj3lCGU-6lbnJWdxqcPkBCMkUf8P2xxwMUrFjI-mNNT-X8QEBxA18p1IXsGS5wjiscVMv&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`, it works fine, and output is corect. Does somebody have an idea what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `#` from your request. Because after `#` sign url **will not be phrased**. The `#` sign commonly use to indicate specific `DOM element id`.

**Your `URL` should be like,**

`http://localhost:997/?state=pass-through%20value&access_token=ya29.ImC6B1g9LYsf5siso8n_UphOFB0SXc5dqsm6LqHRWXbtNHisEblxjeLoYtGgwSVtCTGxOjjODiuTyH7VCHoZCEfUd_&token_type=Bearer&expires_in=3599&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly`

Also refer this [QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312297/unable-to-get-value-of-get-parameter-in-url-with)

---

**If you** want to use `#` to pass `Dom element id`, you should use it at the end of the `url`

`?param=sasad&param2=adsasa#my_element`

If **`#`** is a part of your parameter, Then you should encode it to **`%23`**.. **OR** You should send it in **post request body**

Comment: Thanks for response! But this URL is redirect-url from google OAuth2, am I able to change it somehow and still have it as query?

Comment: The redirect-url is given by you right? Because you are saying google to redirect to that URL after successful authentication. So you should fix in your side.

Comment: Well, redirect-url looks for now https://tolocalhost.com, because i cant just put localhost there. To be honest - I dont have idea how to do it. I've tried get `request.url` and parse it by myself, but it seems like dumb idea. Any better?

Comment: I don't think.Then you should do it manually using `request.url`.

Comment: Thank you for help anyway :)